# Firefox Web Developer Network Timings

Tags: http, firefox, timing

I was trying to use the "Network" tab under "Web Developer" to look at the response time for a web request to a REST HTTP server on a locally hosted VM with a trivial GET URL.  I was surprised to see the time in the 43+ milliseconds range.  The timing on the server side was less than 1 millisecond.  Running curl on the server side resulted in a %time_total less than 1 ms.  Running a python program that created a client socket and hit the same server on the windows side (same as firefox) was also less than 1 ms.

Maybe I'm not understanding what the "Receiving" line on the "Timings" graph for a particular request is actually trying to tell me.   What is it doing besides reading from the socket?  Does this "Receiving" time include the parsing of the response?  Not just the time to read the bytes?

I'm using Firefox 84.0 64-bit on Windows 10.

Thanks I'd like to understand how to accurately measure the time things are taking and firefox either isn't reporting it accurately or there is a behavior that it does that the python program doesn't.